# How to reference an InputField in Unity 5 using C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to reference an `InputField` within Unity 5 using C#, but cannot figure out how to.

My goal is to take the text from the `InputField` when a button is clicked and use that text as a variable within other parts of the project.

I've tried using `GameObject.Find("IPInput").GetComponent<Text>();` but that doesn't seem to work. I am using `UnityEngine.UI` so it's not that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're confusing the static `Text` component with `InputField`. Try this:

```
InputField field = GameObject.Find("IPInput").GetComponent<InputField>();
Debug.Log(field.text);
```

Side note, it's not very efficient to query by GameObject name so depending on what you're doing, you might want to just add this field to your component handling the button click:

```
public InputField field;
```

Then drag the input field into there in the inspector, and you won't have to call `GameObject.Find()` or `GetComponent()`. Much better than hard-coded object names.